# How to test if a particular configuration section exists in an INI file using Nini library?

Tags: c#, configuration, ini, nini

I have been looking for how to test if a particular INI file section exists but not so easy...

For example this INI file :

```
[MySQL]
server = "localhost"
user = "root"
```

In C# I would have to do the following to access the server and user keys and values :

```
IniConfigSource iniFile = new IniConfigSource("file.ini");
string serverHostName = iniFile.Configs["MySQL"].GetString("server");
```

but what if I want to test if [MySQL] section exists. I cannot use the following `Contains` method which asks for a IConfig object not for a string :

```
if (iniFile.Configs.Contains(....))
```

Any idea on how to test this easily ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following code to test whether or not the `ConfigCollection` of your `IniConfigSource` instance contains a section with a given name:

```
IniConfigSource iniFile = new IniConfigSource("file.ini");

if(iniFile.Configs["MySQL"] != null)
{
  // Ini-File contains section
  ...
}
else
{
  // Ini-File does not contain section
  ...
}
```

Hope, this helps.